# Data encrypted in SQL Server 2008 doesn't work in 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have encrypted card info in SQL Server 2008. After migrating to SQL Server 2008 R2, the application cannot decrypt the credit card column.

Does it have anything to do with new master key for 2008 R2? What is causing the problem?

Comment: How were you encrypting the data? Is this on the same physical hardware?

Answer (score 0):

have you check the collation in Extended properties has been changes after migration  ? [image]